# If the textbox val is empty then gets added to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to save student details in the database. In the front end i have a table which takes the student id, name and phone number .

```
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center">1</td>

<td>Name</td>

<td><input type="text" value="sname"></td> 

<td>Mobile</td>

<td><input type="text" value="smob"></td> 
.....
</tr>
</table>
```

Now if i save more than one student detail i am adding to array but the mobile is not mandate .

Now while saving into array if mob is empty it takes as empty string

```
 var i=0;
  jQuery("table tr".each(function()
  {

  name=jQuery(this).find('name').val();

  mob=jQuery(this).find(smob).val();

  name[i]=name;

   mob[i]=mob;

  });
```

Now if the mob say i am saving three details and if mob is empty

then the array mob[i]=["",1,""];

How to add to array if it is not empty such that the mobile number corresponds to the student

Comment: Hope it will helpful (if i understand your question correctly) - http://jsfiddle.net/ZEf2Z/2/ (updated)

Comment: Its not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: actually the prob is name is mandate mobile is optional. if the student is not having a mob number then if i dont add to array then it will not correspond to student name because say if name[]={ABC,DEF}and mob is empty for ABC , then if i dont add to array then mob[] ={fgfg"} which will then correspond to ABC student which is wrong . How to do it in such a way that it corresponds to the correct student

Comment: code doesn't really make sense. You are using tag selectors and looking for them in `value`. Html is incomplete and selectors are incorrect

Comment: i am not having doubts in html i am itering a row and getting the value of textboxes for name and mobile number

Comment: that isn't what the code shown will do. I suggest you make a demo in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way how to solve this problem is to create an array of Students. Note that there are several syntax errors in the code above like 1.

```
jQuery("table tr"
```

should be

```
jQuery("table tr")
```

and 2. the jquery find should be based on some identifier e.g. attribute, id, class, index 3. you are resusing the variables name and mob for different purposes first as an array then as a variable within the loop which causes the values to be overwritten.

you can find an example solution at http://jsfiddle.net/TZ4PH/

Comment: wil modify the code can you tell me how to create array of students i am a fresher to jquery

Comment: yes it will add an empty string, in the attached example, we create an array of students which will contain id,name and mobile - if the fields are empty the value will ""

Comment: okay how to create array of students in javascript pls guide me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TZ4PH/3/ - you have two approaches either using jquery.map or using .each and create objects. I hope this help :)